Build vs Start reacting differently with animation
I have been working on my portfolio website and got it to a decent place, when I actually deployed it though the animation that works great using NPM start on localHost is not working at all on the deployed version. There are no errors in my localhost or build.
GIF of how it looks on LocalHost:

Image of how it looks on webpage:

Here is my TSX:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

import "./header.styles.scss";

const Header: React.FC = () => {
  const [path, setPath] = useState("headerContainer");
  let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname === "/") {
      setPath("headerContainer");
    } else {
      setPath("otherHeaderContainer");
    }
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <div className={path}>
      <Link
        to={location.pathname === "/resume" ? "/" : "/resume"}
        className="linkContainerResume"
      >
        <div>{location.pathname === "/resume" ? "Home" : "Resume"}</div>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/" className="nameContainer">
        <div className="name">Josh Dietrich</div>
        <div className="titleContainer">
          <div className="title">Web Developer</div>
        </div>
      </Link>
      <Link
        to={location.pathname === "/about" ? "/" : "/about"}
        className="linkContainerAbout"
      >
        <div>{location.pathname === "/about" ? "Home" : "About"}</div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;

Here is my SCSS:
@import "../../Assets/styleVariables.scss";
@import "./header.animation.scss";

.headerContainer,
.otherHeaderContainer {
  font-family: $header-font;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100rem;
  width: 95vw;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);

  .nameContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;

    .name {
      color: $blue-color;
      font-size: 5rem;
      filter: saturate(150%);
    }
    .titleContainer {
      .title {
        color: $pink-color;
        font-size: 2rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
    }
  }
  .linkContainerAbout,
  .linkContainerResume {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}

.headerContainer {
  justify-content: center;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 200;
  height: 100vh;

  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  .nameContainer {
    position: absolute;

    animation: namePositionAnimation 1s ease-in-out;
    animation-timeline: scroll(block nearest);

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    .name {
      animation: nameAnimation 1s ease-in-out;
      animation-timeline: scroll(block nearest);
    }
    .titleContainer {
      overflow: hidden;
      .title {
      }
      animation: titleAnimation 1s ease-in-out;
      animation-timeline: scroll(block nearest);
    }
  }

  .linkContainerAbout,
  .linkContainerResume {
    animation: linksAnimation 1s ease-in-out;
    animation-timeline: scroll(block nearest);
  }

  .linkContainerResume {
    color: $blue-color;
  }
  .linkContainerAbout {
    color: $pink-color;
  }

  animation: scrollAnimation 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-timeline: scroll(block nearest);
}

.otherHeaderContainer {
  height: 10rem;
  border-bottom: 3px solid $pink-color;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 $blue-color;
  border-radius: 6rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: -12rem;
  background-color: black;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;

  .nameContainer {
    .name {
    }
    .titleContainer {
      .title {
      }
    }
  }

  .linkContainerAbout {
    margin-right: 2rem;
    color: $blue-color;
  }
  .linkContainerResume {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    color: $pink-color;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .headerContainer {
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 2rem;
    .nameContainer {
      margin-left: -2.5rem;
    }
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
}

Here is my animation scss
@keyframes scrollAnimation {
  0% {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  23% {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  28% {
    height: 10rem;
    max-width: 100rem;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 0.3rem solid $blue-color;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3rem;
  }
  100% {
    height: 10rem;
    width: 100rem;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 0.3rem solid $blue-color;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3rem;
  }
}

@keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
  }
  25% {
    height: 3rem;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  43% {
    height: 0;
    transform: translateY(-2rem);
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
    transform: translateY(-2rem);
  }
}

@keyframes nameAnimation {
  0% {
  }
  25% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  43% {
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 0 $pink-color;
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 0 $pink-color;
  }
}

@keyframes namePositionAnimation {
  0% {
    left: 80%;
    top: 15%;
    width: 50rem;
  }
  25% {
    top: 50%;
    left: 80%;
    width: 50rem;
  }
  43% {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
  }
}

@keyframes linksAnimation {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    margin: 0;
  }
  30% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-right: 15rem;
    margin-left: 15rem;
  }
  35% {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 100;
    margin-right: 32rem;
    margin-left: 32rem;
  }
  100% {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 100;
    margin-right: 32rem;
    margin-left: 32rem;
  }
}

I have tried importing the animation scss directly to the header.tsx. I would like some assistance to understand why the localHost is working differently than the build deploy
